# Navigate between plugin page in wordpress in the backend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am looking for the right way to navigate between plugin page and forms
Let me explain
If I have
A folder contain 2 PHP files
List and New/edit

In the list I show all the data from database and with tow link edit, and delete

Well When I click on edit, I would like to submit the id of the item to the page new/edit and retrieve the data there

When I click on delete, I would like to call Ajax

Therefore, I am looking for the good way to call the new/edit page 
Moreover, call a function in a page to delete the item

Comment: check wp_list_table from wordpress which gives more flexibility.

Comment: Well, I dont realy understand you, but for exemple how I could call a function with Ajax in one of my pages?